# Toggle hover based on toggle status of button

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, bind

If the `mainCircle`'s clicked, I want it to look depressed, which is why when `.mainCircle: active` has no `box-shadow`. However, when I hover over the clicked `mainCircle`, I don't want the hover style to occur (ie, no `box shadow`). I've tried `$(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')` & an if-statement that checks if `mainCircle` is clicked using the `data()` function, and toggles the `box-shadow` using `toggleClass()`. However, all these solutions have proved to be in vain, and I'm struggling to find a way to resolve the situation. Here's the code in question:

Here's a GIF of the problem (when the mainCircle is clicked, and then hovered over, it still has a box-shadow):

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".subOne").hide();
 $(".subTwo").hide();
 $(".subThree").hide();
 $(".subFour").hide();


$(".mainCircle").bind('click',function(){

 $(this).toggleClass('shadow');
 $(".subOne").slideToggle(250);
 $(".subTwo").slideToggle(250);
 $(".subThree").slideToggle(250);
 $(".subFour").slideToggle(250);

 $(".subOne").toggleClass('activeOne');
 $(".subTwo").toggleClass('activeTwo');
  $(".subThree").toggleClass('activeThree');
 $(".subFour").toggleClass('activeFour');

});

$(".subOne").bind('click',function(){ 
 
 $('.mainCircle').toggleClass('callBackground');
 $('.subTwo').toggleClass('downBackground');
 $('.subThree').toggleClass('hangUpBackground');

 $(".subThree").bind('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('subThreeHangUp');
 });
 
 $(".mainCircle").bind('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('mainCircleCall');
  $(this).css('border','2px red solid')
 });
 
});
 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.subContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.mainCircle,
.subOne,
.subTwo,
.subThree,
.subFour {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 10px black;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.mainCircle{
 width: 150px;
 height:150px;
 background: #4286f4;
 background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/M9C94Gf/Aws1Fer.png");
 background-position: -10px -7px; 
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.subOne {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background-image: url("https://www.levelaccess.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/CVAA-02-298x300.png");
 background-size: 95% 95%;
 background-position: center center; 
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.subTwo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
 background-image: url("https://bocarecoverycenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Pain_Killer_Addiction_Rehab.png");
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center center;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;

}
.subThree {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 background-image: url("https://www.humankind.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ems-icon-doing-cpr-e1534816990562.png");
 display: visible;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center center;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;

}
.subFour {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
 background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/9/9895.svg");
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center center;
 transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.mainCircle:active {
  box-shadow: none;
 opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
 transform: scale(0.9);
}

.activeOne{
top:20%;
opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;

}

.activeTwo{
top:65%; 
}

.activeThree{
 left: 20%;
}

.activeFour{
 right:20%;
}

.shadow{
 box-shadow: none;
}

.callBackground{
 background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-and-marketing-glyph/64/web-and-marketing-glyph-04-512.png');
 background-size: 80% 80%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.callBackground:hover{
 background-image: url(https://www.falconemergency.com/wp-content/themes/falcon/images/call3.gif);
 background-size: 120% 120%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px greenyellow solid;
}

.mainCircleCall{
 background-image: url(https://www.falconemergency.com/wp-content/themes/falcon/images/call3.gif);
 background-size: 120% 120%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px greenyellow solid;
}

.downBackground{
 background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmhE2xQpAQ5Zui-0KXRIzEiEvlqjt_ZoojTb9P5d7TU80PP4GHqw');
 animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: 50%;
 margin-right: 50%;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
   }
   25% {
      transform: translateY(3px);
   }
   50% {
      transform: translateY(-3px);
   }
   75% {
      transform: translateY(-6px);
   }
 100%{
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

.hangUpBackground{
 background-image: url(https://png.pngtree.com/svg/20170310/ab2d1aa29d.svg);
 background-size: 80% 80%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.hangUpBackground:hover{
 background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/eb/db/ddebdb230c1193f2593cae1140b24e49.gif);
 background-size: 160% 160%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.subThreeHangUp{
 background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/eb/db/ddebdb230c1193f2593cae1140b24e49.gif);
 background-size: 160% 160%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
}

.mainCircle:not(.shadow):hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px black;
 cursor: pointer; 
 opacity: 0.8;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "subContainer">
  <div class = "mainCircle"></div>
 </div>
  <div class = "subOne"></div>
  <div class = "subTwo"></div>
  <div class = "subThree"></div>
  <div class = "subFour"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the full code: https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/drWGZp?editors=0010

Comment: `.mainCircle:not(:active):hover` OR to avoid the hover when the `shadow` class added `.mainCircle:not(.shadow):hover`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, Just to clarify, that tag applies styles when `mainCircle` it's NOT active, but IS hovered over?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef So why doesn't `.mainCircle:not(.shadow):hover{
 box-shadow: none;
} ` work?

Comment: doesn't work? it works for me .. what I understand from your question is: you want to avoid the hover style when the `mainCircle` is clicked  (if the `mainCircle` has a class shadow).. right??

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Exactly, but it doesn't work on my browser. I'm on Chrome 72; MacOS Mojave

Comment: This is how it looks in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzJedO)

Comment: you don't need another `:hover`  just replace `.mainCircle:hover { ` with `.mainCircle:not(.shadow):hover {`

Comment: Ah, that's why! Thanks

Comment: You're totally welcome.. you may need the same thing for the `callbackground` same thing `.callBackground:not(.shadow):hover{` .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Wow, awesome; Thanks for the help @Mohamed-Yousef